# Playframework 2.1 slow resolving of internal dependencies

Tags: playframework-2.0, dependencies, sbt, resolve

We're using a in house sonatype repository for our own libraries which our play project depend upon. Lately the project have been taking around 10 minutes to start (using play run) because the resolving is slow.

Trying to see what's happening I'm running a `ngrep port 80`. I see alot of slow responses from the typesafe repository which answer that our own libraries isn't in their repo.

Example:

```
T <my-internal-ip>:41907 -> 54.236.91.228:80 [AP]
  HEAD /typesafe/snapshots/<our-pom-file-here> HT
  TP/1.1..User-Agent: Apache Ivy/2.3.0-rc1..Host: repo.typesafe.com..Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2..Connection: keep-alive....                                         
#########
T 54.236.91.228:80 -> <my-iternal-ip>:41907 [AP]
  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found..Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1..Date: Wed, 07 May 2014 
  14:10:32 GMT..Server: Artifactory/3.2.0..X-Artifactory-Id: typesafe2-use-1e-typesafereadonly..Connection: keep-alive....
```

So I would like sbt to search our own repository first which it dosen't seem to be doing at the moment. We've added our repositories in Build.scala like:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
[...]
.settings(
  [...]
  resolvers += "nexus" at "<URL>",
  [...]
```

Any suggestions how to tell sbt to search our local repos before trying with typesafe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the `resolvers`. Currently you're appending your repository after the Type Safe's resolver. You can type `show resolvers` to show the list of currently declared resolvers.

If you want your repository to come before typesafe you have to replace the current list. Instead of `+=` override the key by either `:=` (SBT 0.13.x or newer) or `~=` for older SBT versions.

#### Play 2.1.x (SBT 0.12.x)

```
resolvers ~= ( resolvers => ("My Company Releases" at "http://mycompany.com/releases") +: resolvers)
```

#### Play 2.2.x (SBT 0.13 or greater)

```
resolvers := ("My Company Releases" at "http://mycompany.com/releases") +: resolvers.value
```

This will not override all resolvers. There are also `externalResolvers`, which may be overridden as it is [described in the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Getting-Started/Library-Dependencies.html#overriding-default-resolvers)

Comment: Yes that's more like it, is it possible to prepend to this list or maybe merge with the current resolvers? Just so I won't need to update the list myself if the play developers change the resolvers in a newer release.

Comment: @r0stig you can get the value of the current setting, please check my updated answer, if it doesn't work let me know which SBT version is your Play using (type `about` in play console)

Comment: No that won't work: value value is not a member of sbt.SettingKey[Seq[sbt.Resolver]]

I'm using sbt 0.12.2, does the value property exists in newer versions of sbt?

Comment: @r0stig sorry my bad I didn't notice you're talking about play 2.1 - you can do the same - just the syntax for sbt 0.12.x is different. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you alot, the repositories is now shown with my repos prepended! :)

Comment: Haha I will once I get 15 rep :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use routing rules to preclude the typesafe repo from being hit for internal components. The system actually ships with a few sample org.company | com.company examples for this exact case.
http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-routes.html

Also if you are using a group repository, you can order your local repos above all the external ones because the cost to resolve is much lower. There are cases where routing still helps so for internal components you should do both.

Comment: I don't get it, the problem I'm having is that sbt is asking the typesafe repo (external repo, not our company's) for our internal components before trying to ask our local repos. So adding routing rules to our local sonatype repo won't do anything?

Comment: @r0stig I'm having the same problem. Did you ever solve the problem?