# How to add some local maven repo url to global sbt, and make them be tried first?

Tags: scala, maven, repository, sbt

I want to add some fast local maven repository url to sbt, say:

```
http://maven.example.com/public
```

I want to add it to "global", so that I don't need to add them to each of sbt project. And also want to be tried first when sbt downloading some jars.

But I can't find useful information to do this, how to do it?

(My sbt version is 0.13.1)

Comment: See my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520558/playframework-2-1-slow-resolving-of-internal-dependencies and here it's described where the global config is held: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Global-Settings

Answer (score 7):

With the help of a friend, finally I found the solution:

1. create a new file `~/.sbt/repositories`
2. add content like this:

   ```
   [repositories]
   local
   my-maven-repo: http://example.org/repo
   my-ivy-repo: http://example.org/ivy-repo/, [organization]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
   ```

See official doc: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html#override-all-resolvers-for-all-builds

Comment: Without needing to be an expert in sbt or maven, how do we do this? Can you provide an example (using some foo.bar repo).

Answer (score 2):

Modify your [global configuration file](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Global-Settings#basic-global-configuration-file), which is normally located in `~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt`, if it's not there you can create it.

In the file add following line:

```
externalResolvers := { ("Fast Repo" at "http://maven.example.com/public") +: externalResolvers.value }
```

You can confirm it's working by executing `show externalResolvers` in any project to see the list of resolvers. Your newly added resolver should be first.